# How to set fixed width and height for grid row which is dynamically generating in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I have one asp.net grid view. This rows and columns are dynamically generating based on the retrieved values from database. In .aspx page i use grid
`<asp:GridView Height="250" Width="100%" runat="server" />`

If I have the more number of rows then The grid is appearing like below.
[image]

If I have only one row grid is appearing like below.
[image]

But I want to show the grid rows height same as first image even if there is single row.
How to set the grid row height values as fixed. I found some similar questions like this in stackoverflow. But those didn't give me  the solution.

Comment: Remove the `height=250`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `GridView.RowStyle Property` for defining the row style

**[GridView.RowStyle Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowstyle.aspx):** Gets a reference to the TableItemStyle object that enables you to set the appearance of the data rows in a GridView control.

Eg.

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1">
        <rowstyle Height="20px" />
        <alternatingrowstyle  Height="20px"/>
</asp:GridView>
```

Comment: If I use `alternatingrowstyle` it is giving me error. `<rowstyle >` is working fine now.

Answer (score 2):

CSS :
/*grid*/

```
.MoGrid { width: 100%; background-color: #fff; margin: 5px 0 10px 0;}

.MoGrid td { color: #F05117;font-family: georgia;font-weight: bold;padding: 30px 2px 2px;}

.MoGrid th {border-bottom: 1px solid #F05117;border-top: 1px solid #F05117;color: #29B6EA;
    font-size: 13px;font-weight: bold;padding: 4px 2px;font-family: georgia;}

.MoGrid .alt { background: #fcfcfc url(../Styles/images/grd_alt.png) repeat-x top; }

.MoGrid .pgrM {background: #29B6EA; height:10px; }

.MoGrid .pgrM table { margin: 5px 0; }

.MoGrid .pgrM td { border-width: 0; padding: 0 6px; border-left: solid 1px #666; font-weight: bold; color: #fff; line-height: 12px; float:left; }  

.MoGrid .pgrM a { color: #666; text-decoration: none; }

.MoGrid .pgrM a:hover { font-family: tahoma;font-size: 12px;background-color: #99BBE1; }
```

SOURCE :

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView2" runat="server" CssClass="MoGrid"       
PagerStyle-CssClass="pgrM" AlternatingRowStyle-CssClass="alt">
```

Answer (score 2):

Little bit tricky but work for me.
You can make the gridview fixed height by stating the height (in px) of the gridview itself. Now to make the rows contract down to their appropriate height (rather than expanding to fill the void) set the Height of the Footer Style to 100%. This ensures that even if the number of records displayed is less than the paging size the footer will take up the slack, leaving the data rows in their original "unexpanded" state.

First:

```
showfooter="true"
```

in grid.

and in footerstyle :

```
  <footerstyle Height="100%" />
```

Comment: Not a good one brother. Actually in my case no need of paging. If use `showfooter` then it is displaying one blank line under, which is not good to see

Comment: Yep, paging was my case and this worked. Thanks @Shree

Answer (score 1):

you can use  RowStyle-Height="20" property of gridview with this code onPage_PreRender

for example

```
if(grdView.Rows.Count>0)
grdView.Height = new Unit(grdView.RowStyle.Height.Value * grdView.Rows.Count);
```

Or `remove Height property from gridView`

Comment: In my grid the values will come based on the search result. when we search the entire page will not postback right!! Then in that case how this will work?

Comment: But search results you get from database after databind?

Answer (score 0):

**Lot of ways there**

**Mention the height value for RowStyle(& AlternateRowStyle) in your HTML source**

```
<rowstyle height="50" />
```

**You can do that same in code-behind**

```
GridView1.RowStyle.Height = 50;
```

**But my suggestion is use CSS(Best way)**

```
.RowStyle {
  height: 50px;
}
.AlternateRowStyle {
  height: 50px;
}
```

**ASP source**

```
<asp:gridview id="GridView1" runat="server" xmlns:asp="#unknown">
<rowstyle cssclass="RowStyle" />
<alternatingrowstyle cssclass="AlternateRowStyle" />
</asp:gridview>
```

*Thank you*