# How to set row height of two gridviews equal in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview

I have two Gridviews. Both of which have autogenerated columns. But these two gridviews have the same number of rows. What I need to do is to set the row height of these two gridviews equal. I tried using the RowDataBound event of the gridviews but it isn't working.

This is the preview of how the Gridviews should look like:

[image]

This is the rowdatabound events I'm trying to build but it's not really working:

```
Private Sub GridView1_RowDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles GridView1.RowDataBound   
    Dim gv1
    Dim gv2
    For i = 0 To e.Row.Cells.Count - 1
        e.Row.Cells(i).Width = Page.Request.Browser.ScreenPixelsWidth
        gv1 = GridView1.Rows(i).Height
        gv2 = GridView2.Rows(i).Height

        If gv2 > gv1 Then
            e.Row.Cells(i).Height = gv2
        End If
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub GridView2_RowDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles GridView2.RowDataBound
    Dim gv1
    Dim gv2
    For i = 0 To e.Row.Cells.Count - 1
        e.Row.Cells(i).Width = Page.Request.Browser.ScreenPixelsWidth
        gv1 = GridView1.Rows(i).Height
        gv2 = GridView2.Rows(i).Height

        If gv1 > gv2 Then
            e.Row.Cells(i).Height = gv1
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Please advise. Thanks.

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13762220/how-to-set-fixed-width-and-height-for-grid-row-which-is-dynamically-generating-i

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may not be able to do this on server side. You have to use j query for that:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            SetHeight();
        });

function SetHeight() {

            $("#GridView2 > tbody > tr").each(function (i, tr) {
                if ($("#GridView2 > tbody > tr:nth-child(" + (i + 1) + ")").height() > $("#GridView1 > tbody > tr:nth-child(" + (i + 1) + ")").height()) {
                    $("#GridView1 > tbody > tr:nth-child(" + (i + 1) + ")").height($("#GridView2 > tbody > tr:nth-child(" + (i + 1) + ")").height());
                } else {                  
                    $("#GridView2 > tbody > tr:nth-child(" + (i + 1) + ")").height($("#GridView1 > tbody > tr:nth-child(" + (i + 1) + ")").height());
                }

            });
        }
```

Comment: Hi! I tried using the jquery function but it's not working. Should i call it in code behind using RegisterClientScriptBlock? Thanks!

Comment: @lulutanseco are u getting any error in console? from  RegisterClientScriptBlock it will not work because grid is not loaded in Ui when function is called so it should be within document ready

Comment: There's no error in the console but the row heights of two Gridviews are still not the equal :(

Comment: @lulutanseco debug j query and check whether it loops all rows and settings height or not because solution is working in my test project.

Comment: chances are that `#GridView1` and `#Gridview2` are not the real id's of the rendered html unless both  grids (or the page) has `ClientIDMode="Static"`

Comment: Yes, I changed them correspondingly. I think, the problem is I have a template field I just added with buttons on it. And these buttons have definite heights in pixels. When I removed the "row height" attribute and the template field, it is working. Thanks. :) I will find a way to go around this without removing my template field.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, since the rows seem to always have a 1:1 correspondence, if you have access to the sql statements that generate the 2 grids you *could* rework the sql to return one table and format the gridview to *look* like 2 grids as in your diagram.

This way you wouldn't have to worry about the row heights at all.

Come to think of it, you could just manipulate the 2 datasources into a new DataTable and *then* populate one gridview.

Comment: I would like to do that originally. But the system user would like 1 gridview with various row commands while the other gridview is purely static, so they instructed me to use two gridviews. But I will try recommending that. :) thanks

Comment: Understood, but just fyi, you can also do that with one gridview, just make the "static" data readonly so they're uneditable when you select a row to edit.